# Injecting incremental counter in a bidimentional array

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, matrix, data-structures

Having this matrix structure:

```
irb(main):026:0> data["rows"].flatten.map{|c1|c1["f"].map{|c2|c2["v"]}}
=> [["IssueCommentEvent", "369"], ["WatchEvent", "2217"], ["IssuesEvent", "65"], ["ForkEvent", "136"], ["PushEvent", "51"], ["PullRequestReviewCommentEvent", "69"], ["PullRequestEvent", "116"], ["PublicEvent", "1"], ["CommitCommentEvent", "9"]]
irb(main):027:0>
```

how can I add incremental counter as an element of innermost array?

Wanted resoult:

```
[["1", "IssueCommentEvent", "369"], ["2", "WatchEvent", "2217"], ["3", "IssuesEvent", "65"], ["4", "ForkEvent", "136"], ["5", "PushEvent", "51"], ["6", "PullRequestReviewCommentEvent", "69"], ["7", "PullRequestEvent", "116"], ["8", "PublicEvent", "1"], ["9", "CommitCommentEvent", "9"]]
```

I tried the following but it breaks the structure adding one more dimension:

```
irb(main):033:0>data["rows"].flatten.map{|c1|c1["f"].map{|c2|c2["v"]}}.map.with_index(1).to_a
=> [[["IssueCommentEvent", "369"], 1], [["WatchEvent", "2217"], 2], [["IssuesEvent", "65"], 3], [["ForkEvent", "136"], 4], [["PushEvent", "51"], 5], [["PullRequestReviewCommentEvent", "69"], 6], [["PullRequestEvent", "116"], 7], [["PublicEvent", "1"], 8], [["CommitCommentEvent", "9"], 9]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
arr = [
  ["IssueCommentEvent", "369"], ["WatchEvent", "2217"],
  ["IssuesEvent", "65"],        ["ForkEvent", "136"],
  ["PushEvent", "51"],          ["PullRequestReviewCommentEvent", "69"],
  ["PullRequestEvent", "116"],  ["PublicEvent", "1"],
  ["CommitCommentEvent", "9"]]

arr.map.with_index(1) { |a,i| [i.to_s] + a }
  #=> [["1", "IssueCommentEvent", "369"],
  #    ["2", "WatchEvent", "2217"],
  # ...
  #    ["9", "CommitCommentEvent", "9"]]
```

If you'd prefer to modify `arr`, then use:

```
arr.map.with_index(1) { |a,i| a.unshift(i.to_s) }
```

Comment: Hey Cary, ... you also share an amazing story in your profile. Nice to meet you.

Comment: @LucaG.Soave, grazie, e buona di conoscerti.